# Cubic Root of Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I understand how to take cubic root of both positive and negative numbers. But when trying to use `apply`-`lambda` method to efficiently process all elements of a dataframe, I run into an ambiguity issue. Interestingly, this error does not arise with equalities, so I am wondering what could be wrong with the code:

```
sample[columns]=sample[columns].apply(lambda x: (-1)*np.power(-x,1./3) if x<0 else np.power(x,1./3))
```

Comment: Can you also provide a working exemple which reproduce the error ? Tried it on a sample it worked just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are passing a list or array of column names.  I assume this because your variable name is plural with an `s` at the end.  If this is the case, then `sample[columns]` is a dataframe.  This is an issue because `apply` iterates through each column, passing that column the `lambda` you passed to `apply`.  So you get

```
(-1) * np.power(-series_object, -1./3) if series_object < 0 else...
```

And it's the `series_object < 0` that is messing things up because you are asking for the truthiness of a whole series being less than zero.

---

**`applymap`**

```
f = lambda x: -np.power(-x, 1./3) if x < 0 else np.power(x, 1./3)
sample[columns] = sample[columns].applymap(f)
```

---

That said, I'd use a `lambda` defined as follows

```
f = lambda x: np.sign(x) * np.power(abs(x), 1./3)
```

Then you could perform this on the entire dataframe

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-10, 10, (5, 5)))

df

    0  1   2  3   4
0   6  1  -8  0   5
1   3  1   3  9  -2
2 -10  2 -10 -8 -10
3  -3  9   3  8   2
4  -6 -7   9  3  -3
```

---

```
f = lambda x: np.sign(x) * np.power(abs(x), 1./3)
f(df)

          0         1         2         3         4
0  1.817121  1.000000 -2.000000  0.000000  1.709976
1  1.442250  1.000000  1.442250  2.080084 -1.259921
2 -2.154435  1.259921 -2.154435 -2.000000 -2.154435
3 -1.442250  2.080084  1.442250  2.000000  1.259921
4 -1.817121 -1.912931  2.080084  1.442250 -1.442250
```

Same as

```
df.applymap(f)

          0         1         2         3         4
0  1.817121  1.000000 -2.000000  0.000000  1.709976
1  1.442250  1.000000  1.442250  2.080084 -1.259921
2 -2.154435  1.259921 -2.154435 -2.000000 -2.154435
3 -1.442250  2.080084  1.442250  2.000000  1.259921
4 -1.817121 -1.912931  2.080084  1.442250 -1.442250
```

---

Check for equality

```
df.applymap(f).equals(f(df))

True
```

---

And its faster

```
%timeit df.applymap(f)
%timeit f(df)

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.11 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 473 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't have to be complicated, simply use NumPys cube-root function: [`np.cbrt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cbrt.html):

```
df[columns] = np.cbrt(df[columns])
```

It requires `NumPy >= 1.10` though.

---

For older versions you could use [`np.absolute`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.absolute.html) and [`np.sign`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) instead of using conditionals:

```
df[columns] = df[columns].apply(lambda x: np.power(np.absolute(x), 1./3) * np.sign(x))
```

This calculates the cube root of the absolute and then changes the sign appropriatly.

Comment: I should've looked for a cube root specific function :-)  Nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
sample[columns]=sample[columns]**(1/3)
```

Comment: Unfortuantely this method does not work with negative values.

Comment: @amirtZ it does not indeed, can you provide a code that reproduce the error ?

Comment: not sure what code you're exactly referring too. But running the original code on a dataframe gives: "The truth value of a DataFrame is ambigous. Use a.empty(), a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Comment: Like posting a sample dataframe that people can run, to see the problem in the future, it's easier for people to solve it. Glad @piRsquared solve your issue still, if you have opperation only on value regardless of index/colmn, it's better to use applymap, way faster since apply return each time a copy of a serie instead of a scalar.